# How do I set the HttpOnly flag on a cookie in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The page *[Protecting Your Cookies: HttpOnly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001167.html)* explains why making HttpOnly cookies is a good idea.

How do I set this property in Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Set the 'http_only' option in the hash used to set a cookie

e.g.

```
cookies["user_name"] = { :value => "david", :httponly => true }
```

or, in Rails 2:

e.g.

```
cookies["user_name"] = { :value => "david", :http_only => true }
```

Comment: Heads up - in rails 3 `:http_only` option was renamed to `:httponly`

Answer (score 12):

Re Laurie's answer:

Note that the option was renamed from `:http_only` to `:httponly` (no underscore) at some point.

In actionpack 3.0.0, that is, Ruby on Rails 3, all references to `:http_only` are gone.

That threw me for a while.

Answer (score 7):

Just set :http_only to true as described in the [changelog](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/changeset/7525).

Answer (score 5):

If you’ve a file called config/session_store.rb including this line (Rails 3+), then it’s automatically set already.
`config/initializers/session_store.rb`:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_my_application_session"
```

Also rails allows you to set following keys:

**:expires** - *The time at which this cookie expires, as a Time object.*

**:secure** - *Whether this cookie is only transmitted to HTTPS servers. Default is false.*

Answer (score 1):

I also wrote a patch that is included in Rails 2.2, which defaults the CookieStore session to be http_only.

Unfortunately session cookies are still by default regular cookies.