# Rails 3 additional session configuration options (key, expires_after, secure)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session-state, session-variables

Can someone point out what the new Rails 3.x session configuration options are?

I'm trying to duplicate the same configuration that I have in my Rails 2.3.x application.

This is the configuration that I used in the application:

```
#environment.rb
config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store

config.action_controller.session = {
    :key         => '_something', #non-secure for development
    :secret      => 'really long random string'
  }


# production.rb - override environment.rb for production
config.action_controller.session = {
  :key            => '_something_secure',
  :secret         => 'really long random string',
  :expire_after   => 60*60,#time in seconds
  :secure         => true #The session will now not be sent or received on HTTP requests.
}
```

However, in Rails 3.x, I can only find mention of the following:

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store

AppName::Application.config.secret_token = 'really long random string'

AppName::Application.config.cookie_secret = 'another really long random string'
```

Are there other config settings to control the key, expire_after time, and secure option?

Regarding the latter, if "config.force_ssl = true" is set in production.rb, I assume the secure option is no longer required?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Expiry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860950/setting-session-timeout-in-rails-3

Comment: Secure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72242/how-do-i-set-the-httponly-flag-on-cookie-in-rails

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You now configure the Cookie-based session store through an initializer, probably in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`. In Rails 3 the session store is a piece of middleware, and the configuration options are passed in with a single call to `config.session_store`:

```
Your::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_session'
```

You can put any extra options you want in the hash with `:key`, e.g.

```
Your::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  :key =>           '_session_id',
  :path =>          '/',
  :domain =>        nil,
  :expire_after =>  nil,
  :secure =>        false,
  :httponly =>      true,
  :cookie_only =>   true
}
```

(Those are just the standard defaults)

If you force SSL in production then setting secure on the cookie shouldn't really make a difference in practice, but you might want to set it just to be on the safe side...

```
Your::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  :key =>           '_session_id',
  :secure =>        Rails.env.production?
}
```

Comment: Looks like that does it!  Thanks for this!

Comment: And also, just to clarify, it appears that these options work on the active_record session store, too.  I noted that the code samples in the above are coded for the cookie store, but I tried these with active_record store (which was what the question asked about) and the options appear to take effect.

Comment: Debugging for an old project, thanks for saving my time.

Comment: Is the :key argument required if the session_store is active_record ? At present I am migrating from 3.0 to 3.2 and rails guide says to change that key http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-initializers-session-store-rb . Is the value of key argument anyway related to secret_token?