# rails 3 not saving session in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I just switched to my production server and I see that the session table is empty. Also no cookies are being set at all.

Here's how my initializer is set:

```
Webapp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, {
    :secure => Rails.env.production?
}
```

Works ok on development. No idea.

Comment: Have you checked the production log?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9277529/1067353?

Comment: seems that the :Secure param chokes if I'm not on https. Someone close this question please

Comment: @RomeoM. Yup, that one bit me too..