# Rails 3 session & cookie how to persist session id cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

I am developing a simple shopping cart based on session_id i.e. for determination of a user cart items used session_id.

But when user closes a browser and then opens it again a **session id** is been changed. And he loses all his items in cart.

I suspect such feature I can provide with saving **session id** in cookie.

Am I right?

Any way my question is **How to provide a functionality that allows users get their cart items even after closing a browser?**

Answer (score 5):

I recommend reading the Rails Guide: Action Controller Overview (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html).

Sections 4 and 5 cover Sessions and Cookies and will give you a deeper understanding
on how to use them and will make it easier to tackle future challenges.

I would also check out the Ruby on Rails ActionDispatch::Cookies < Object Documentation
(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html)

An example of the controller code you are looking for is listed on this resource. Here is an example:

```
# Sets a cookie that expires in 1 hour.
cookies[:login] = { :value => "XJ-122", :expires => 1.hour.from_now }
```

Comment: i am confused. From one hand by default all data that I persist in session (session[:some_key] = some_value) also persisted on user side in cookies. From another hand Rails presents a way to store data in cookie like cookie[:some_key] = some_value. Why store data in cookie[] if I can store it in session[]?

Comment: Some Rails applications do not use sessions but they still may want to store some information on the users browser, that is why the cookies methods exist.

Answer (score 3):

```
cookies[:your_cookie] = {
    :value => "your_cookie_value",
    :expires => 100.years.from_now
}
```

for more details, [check it out](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).

Comment: So..I have to update my cookie everytime my controller changes something that goes to the session, or that goes automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Rails stores the session in a cookie by default. You can influence if
the cookie lives beyond a restart of the browser (see below).

Cookies ARE NOT shared between browsers.  Ever.

If you want to use Opera to look at the shopping cart you just created in Firefox you need to authenticate to the shop in some way, for example with username and password.

See [Rails 3 additional session configuration options (key, expires_after, secure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397573/rails-3-additional-session-configuration-options-key-expires-after-secure) for a description of all the configuration options for your session.

you'll be wanting to look at :expire_after, for example

```
:expire_after => 24.hours
```

(Found here: [Setting session timeout in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860950/setting-session-timeout-in-rails-3))

Comment: Thanks, its clear. But I doesn't work for different browsers. For example I added some items to cart in Firefox then I closed Firefox and opened Opera. Unfortunately in Opera I dont see items that was added in Firefox.